# Fever vs Inflammation

Tags: immunology, terminology

What's the difference between inflammation and fever? And why is fever called an inflammatory response? Does the word inflammation have both a general and a specific meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Inflammation includes accumulation of inflammatory cells, such as neutrophils or macrophags, in a tissue. The typical four local signs of inflammation include redness (Latin rubor), heat (calor), swelling (tumor), and pain (dolor) ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/inflammation)).

Fever is a symptom, which may or may not be present in a certain inflammatory condition. For example, lung inflammation in pneumonia is usually accompanied with fever, while joint inflammation in rheumatoid arthritis is not.